# How to achive this kind of overlay in flutter

Tags: flutter

This kind of overlay, I want to implement this in a flutter

[Overylay Image of What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9jjQ2.png)

So we have two overlays  :

overlay1 = Overlay with listview of tiles

overlay2 = values from hovered list index

How to implement this in  flutter

### I HAVE TRIED BUT NOT working as desired:

This is what I have achieved

[Overylay Image of What I have achieved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7Ocp.png)

Everything works fine Until I change the index then things won't work as desired

```
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';

final overlayIndexProvider = StateProvider<int>((ref) {
  return 0;
});

class RawOverlay extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const RawOverlay({super.key, required this.postion});

  final Offset postion;

  @override
  ConsumerState<RawOverlay> createState() => _RawOverlayState();
}

class _RawOverlayState extends ConsumerState<RawOverlay> {
  List<Widget> overlay2child = [
    Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
      height: 250,
      width: 250,
      child: const Card(
        elevation: 5,
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Text(
              'index 0',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.green),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
    Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
      height: 250,
      width: 250,
      child: const Card(
        elevation: 5,
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Text(
              'index 1',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.green),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    )
  ];

  // int? indexOverlay = 0;
  OverlayEntry? overlayEntry2;
  OverlayEntry? overlayEntry1;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    void removeHighlightOverlay2() {
      if (overlayEntry2!.mounted) {
        overlayEntry2!.remove();
      }
    }

    void showOverlay(BuildContext context) async {
      if (overlayEntry1!.mounted == false) {
        Overlay.of(context).insert(overlayEntry1!);
      }
    }

    void removeHighlightOverlay1() {
      if (overlayEntry1!.mounted) {
        overlayEntry1!.remove();
      }
    }

    // position = _getWidgetPosition();
    overlayEntry2 = OverlayEntry(builder: (context) {
      return Positioned(
        top: widget.postion.dy + 60,
        left: widget.postion.dx + 100,
        child: MouseRegion(
            onExit: (event) {
              final dx = event.position.dx;
              final dy = event.position.dy;
              final widgetX = widget.postion.dx;
              final widgetY = widget.postion.dy;
              final thresholdX = widgetX + 100 + 250;
              final thresholdYMax = widgetY + 60 + 250;
              final thresholdYMin = widgetY + 60;

              if (dx < thresholdX) {
                removeHighlightOverlay2();
              } else if (dx > thresholdX) {
                removeHighlightOverlay2();
                removeHighlightOverlay1();
              }

              dy < thresholdYMin || dy > thresholdYMax
                  ? removeHighlightOverlay1()
                  : null;
            },
            child: overlay2child[ref.watch(overlayIndexProvider)]),
      );
    });

    void showOverlay2(BuildContext context) async {
      if (overlayEntry2!.mounted == false) {
        Overlay.of(context).insert(overlayEntry2!);
      }
    }

    List<Widget> overlay1child = const [
      Text('Name'),
      Text('Date'),
    ];

    overlayEntry1 = OverlayEntry(builder: (context) {
      return Positioned(
        top: widget.postion.dy + 60,
        left: widget.postion.dx,
        child: Column(
          // key: cloumnkey,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            MouseRegion(
              onExit: (event) {
                var dy = event.position.dy;
                if (event.position.dx < widget.postion.dx) {
                  removeHighlightOverlay2();
                  removeHighlightOverlay1();
                } else if (dy < widget.postion.dy + 60 ||
                    dy > widget.postion.dy + 60 + 100) {
                  removeHighlightOverlay1();
                  removeHighlightOverlay2();
                } else {
                  showOverlay2(context);
                }
              },
              child: SizedBox(
                width: 100,
                child: Card(
                  elevation: 5,
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemCount: overlay1child.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return MouseRegion(
                        onExit: (event) {
                          //  removeHighlightOverlay2();
                        },
                        onEnter: (event) {
                          ref.read(overlayIndexProvider.notifier).state = index;

                          // removeHighlightOverlay2();

                          showOverlay2(context);
                        },
                        child: SizedBox(
                          height: 50,
                          child: ListTile(
                              onTap: () {}, title: overlay1child[index]),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    });

    return MouseRegion(
      onEnter: (event) {
        showOverlay(context);
      },
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.green,
        height: 50,
        width: 100,
        child: const Center(
          child: Text('Showoverlay'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```